# how to wrap Drawer with ThemeConsumer in flutter

Tags: flutter

I use theme proviser.I try to wrap each route and dialog in ThemeConsumer, but it dont work with drower,What should i do?.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

      drawer: Drawer( child: ThemeConsumer(child: SettingsPage())),

     )};
```